# Comma not working inside \bm when using babel

Tags: math-mode, bold

When I try to compile this simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\bm{,}$
\end{document}
```

I receive the following complaint:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\it@comma@def  ->\futurelet \let@token
                                       \@@math@comma
l.7 $\bm{,}
           $
```

and a strange number (25915) is printed on the resulting pdf instead of the comma. 
Something odd is going on with the babel package, because if I remove the line

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

everything works just fine. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the “intelligent comma” commands proposed in `italian.ldf` are not really smart.

You can avoid the problem with `\bm` by using

```
\bm{\mathpunct{,}}
```

or

```
\bm{{,}}
```

depending if you want it to be punctuation or an ordinary symbol.